# LightweightChart disappears when updating the data

Tags: swift, tradingview-api, lightweight-charts

i have 4 tabs displaying different resolution. example switching between 1min and 1day. i am also adding real time data to each resolution. when updating the array with real time data and then switching tabs, the chart disappears. the average row still appears but alone without the chart. this is using swift

without updating the read time data, or without switching tabs, both works.  the combination of both make the chart disppears

Comment: Are you using the `update()` method on the series to provide real time updates? [documentation](https://tradingview.github.io/lightweight-charts/docs/next/api/interfaces/ISeriesApi#update). If you are using the update method then could you please create a minimal reproducible example so that we could examine the problem in more detail and offer suggestions?

Comment: thanks for the help. i actually solved it by flipping the order. first updating the bar then updating the array 
yes, im using both setData and update(bar) the viewcontroller is called from the swiftUI UIViewControllerRepresentable